# SQL - How to cross-join two table to repeat values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, cross-join

I have a 2 tables that look like this:

```
MonthEndDate
2016-06-30 00:00:00.000
2016-07-31 00:00:00.000
2016-08-31 00:00:00.000
2016-09-30 00:00:00.000
2016-10-31 00:00:00.000
2016-11-30 00:00:00.000
2016-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

AND

```
MonthEndDate             CustomerId  Flag
2016-06-30 00:00:00.000  123          1
2016-07-31 00:00:00.000  123          1
2016-08-31 00:00:00.000  123          1
2016-09-30 00:00:00.000  123          1
```

I would like an output that looks like this:

```
MonthEndDate             CustomerId     Flag
2016-06-30 00:00:00.000     123          1
2016-07-31 00:00:00.000     123          1
2016-08-31 00:00:00.000     123          1
2016-09-30 00:00:00.000     123          1
2016-10-31 00:00:00.000     123          0
2016-11-30 00:00:00.000     123          0
2016-12-31 00:00:00.000     123          0
```

Table 1 is a `DimDate` table that has month end date.
Table

---

2 is the `CustomerInfo` table.
Each customer has a `Flag` set to `1`  whenever that customer has a value for the given Month End.
I want to get an output that will have every Month End Date (that's why I'm suing `DimDate` table) and when a customer does not have a value for the Month End I want the flag to show 0.
I'm using SQL Server 2005

Here is some sample code I used:

```
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    MonthEndDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES('2016-06-30 00:00:00.000')

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES('2016-07-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES('2016-08-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES('2016-09-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES('2016-10-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES('2016-11-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES('2016-12-31 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
    MonthEndDate DATETIME
    ,CustomerId INT
    ,Flag INT
)

INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES('2016-06-30 00:00:00.000',123,1)

INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES('2016-07-31 00:00:00.000',123,1)
INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES('2016-08-31 00:00:00.000',123,1)
INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES('2016-09-30 00:00:00.000',123,1)

SELECt * FROM  @table1


SELECt * FROM  @table2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a `CROSS JOIN` on to get all combinations of `MonthEndDate` and `CustomerId`. When you have that, do a `LEFT JOIN` on `table2` to get the `Flag`:

```
SELECT
    t1.MonthEndDate,
    c.CustomerId,
    Flag = ISNULL(t2.Flag, 0)
FROM @table1 t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId FROM @table2) c
LEFT JOIN @table2 t2
    ON t1.MonthEndDate = t2.MonthEndDate
    AND c.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
```

Comment: For some reason I never thought to use both Cross and Left. Learn new things every day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.flag, 0) as flag
from @table1 t1 left join
     @table2 t2
     on t1.MonthEndDate = t2.MonthEndDate;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not bring back the CustomerId